# Missing Favicon on Firefox

Tags: bug

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but

The Arduino icon no longer appears on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ although it is on this Meta.

I am using Firefox on macOS, and this probably happened after an upgrade to 53.0.2.

All the other stackexchange.com sites I use are OK

Comment: Hmm sounds like a caching issue. Can you try it on another Mac with Firefox? My Windows 10 computer with Firefox worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my problem is solved, and probably is caching, although who knows.

It continued for several days, despite restarting Firefox. In retrospect I should have cleared the cache.

After a couple of restarts it is now working this morning.

Comment: Please accept your answer, to indicatie that the problem has been solved.